# Updated Semantic MediaWiki but get error when running update.php

Tags: composer-php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, semantic-mediawiki

I used composer to update my semantic `MediaWiki` version. The installation ran successfully but I can't run `update.php`.

I could verify this by using `composer.phar show`. My earlier SMW version was 1.8.05. Running `update.php` gives me an error that says

> SEMANTIC MEDIAWIKI MUST BE INSTALLED TO RUN SEMANTIC FORMS.

I did try placing the `enableSemantics()` call at the end of `LocalSettings.php` file.

Comment: Is SMW actually installed? What does Special:Version say? How does you composer config look?

Comment: Yes, i guess it is since when i run php composer.phar show, it does show me all the new versions that have been installed. But when I try to run php maintenance/update it throws me the error mentioned in the question. I cant open the Special:Version page. the same error is thrown by the browser too

Comment: Is SF enabled with Composer or LocalSettings?

Comment: Did you first disable all the SMW extensions in your LocalSettings file, including those that reference the Semantic Bundle?

Have you also asked the Semantic Mediawiki mailing list? https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki_mailing_lists

Comment: yes i did disable/remove validator and smw extensions as per the instructions given for installation. Also, according to the procedure, we need not include the extensions in the LocalSettings file since after the update the composer takes care of loading them.

Comment: Thanks @Mani, can you embed this additional information in the question text so that it's easier to answer for future readers?